# How to: If fadeIn do not fade again (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple code that when you press a key it fades in a div. When I press it twice, it fades it twice. Is it possible you can prevent this with a simple line or two? Like if fadein do not fadeIn again or something?

The code looks like:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 's',function (evt){
   $("#div1").fadeIn();
   return false;
});
```

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

No sure what you mean. Your code works. Assuming div is hidden by default, when key is pressed, div fades is. If key is pressed again, it will not fadein again since it's already showing, unless of course you are refreshing the page.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/F8s8X/.

Comment: hmm... my script has like 1429 lines of code... probably somewhere else is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isFading = false
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 's',function (evt){
   if(!isFading){
     isFading = true;
     $("#div1").fadeIn(400,function(){ isFading = false; });
     return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$.bind()` use `$.one()`. This will bind your handler to the event and automatically unbind it after the first run.
http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
jQuery(document).one('keydown', 's',function (evt){
   $("#div1").fadeIn();
   return false;
});
```